# Find points at which coldest and hottest temperature on plate occur?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Circular hot plate given by the relationship $x^2+y^2\le4,$ heated according to the spatial temperature function $T(x,y) = 10 - x^2+2x-4y^2$.

Comment: Do you know how to find critical points of $T$?

Comment: set partial derivatives to 0?

Comment: Yes (or where partials don't exist, but that won't happen for a polynomial function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$T(x,y)=11-(x-1)^2-4y^2\ .$$
This shows that $T(x,y)\leq T(1,0)=11$ for all $(x,y)\in D$, and the maximum value $11$ is taken only at the point $(1,0)$.

It is obvious that $(1,0)$ is the only stationary point of $T$ in the interior of $D$. Therefore the minimum of $T$ has to occur on the boundary $\partial D$. In order to find it we parametrize $\partial D$ by means of
$$\partial D:\quad\phi\mapsto(2\cos\phi,2\sin\phi)\qquad(\phi\in{\mathbb R})$$
and consider the pullback
$$f(\phi):=T(2\cos\phi,2\sin\phi)=\ldots=12\cos^2\phi+4\cos\phi-6\ .$$
The derivative
$$f'(\phi)=-(24\cos\phi+4)\sin\phi$$
vanishes when $\cos\phi=-{1\over6}$ or $\sin\phi=0$. This leads to $4$ conditionally stationary points of $T$ on $\partial D$, namely
$$\left(-{1\over3},{1\over3}\sqrt{35}\right),\quad \left(-{1\over3},-{1\over3}\sqrt{35}\right),\quad (2,0),\quad(-2,0)\ .\tag{1}$$
When $\cos\phi=-{1\over6}$ then $f(\phi)=-{19\over3}$, and when $\sin\phi=0$ then $f(\phi)=6\pm 4>0$. It follows that the minimum of $T$ on $D$ is $-{19\over3}$, and it is taken at the first two points listed in $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem require to find the maximum and minimum of the function T within the given constraint.

The straightforward method is to study the function, i.e., computing it's asymptotic behaviour and checking it's derivatives.

Note that the function is symmetric in y, and decrreasing with the magnitude of it. Setting dT/dx=0 will find the maximum (you should check it's a maximum!).

Pay attention that setting the derivative to zero doesn't give all the result required: T has not global minimum. But as we already saw that T it's symmetrical and decreasing in y, the problem reduce to comput the minimum on the disc border. This can be achieved setting x^2+y^2=4, finding y in function of x, substituting the found expression for y in T and, finally, computing the minimum of Newly defined T. Remember that as T is symmetrix in y you will have two equal minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There are alternatives to calculus in such cases - unless you want to use it.  To find the hottest point, for e.g. note:
$$T(x,y) = 11 - (x-1)^2 - 4y^2$$
Now it should be evident what the hottest temperature is and where the hottest point is - where the squares are zero, you need to verify it is in the feasible region.

Finding the coldest point is only slightly longer. Using $y^2 \le 4-x^2$ we rewrite:
$$ T(x, y) = 10-x^2+2x - 4y^2 \ge 10-x^2+2x- 16 + 4x^2 = 3x^2 + 2x - 6$$
$$\implies T(x,y) \ge 3\left(x+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^2  - \dfrac{19}{3}$$

Noting when equality is achieved, one can read out the coldest temperature and find where (two points) it is coldest.